# I use I/O in java i need a function when i use in.nextInt return from the first to read the file again

Tags: java, io, repeat

I use I/O in java and  i need a function when i use in.nextInt  return to the first to read the file again

for example i have file with 3 line and my object reading is ( in ) 
if i Write in.nextLine 3  time  , i will be in the end and i cant return to read the file again

i need to know if i can use any function which make the reading from the first

```
try {

    Scanner in=new Scanner(new FileInputStream ("test.txt"));
    /*
     in my text {1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 }
     */
    while (in.hasNextInt())
    {
        System.out.print(in.nextInt());

    }
    //now i'm in the end and i need to repeat my reading again ( how ) 
    while (in.hasNextInt())
    {
        System.out.print(in.nextInt());

    }

}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to read the file again? You could just store the values in an array or so when reading the first time

Comment: because i have array number in the file and i need to count the row and the columns after that i will read from the file 1

Comment: Still not necessary. You can always store file contents as, say, an array of strings, and then split one of the strings by whatever your column separator is to get the column count.

Comment: oooh my god, what I was asking here 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always create a new Scanner instance to read the file again :

```
Scanner in=new Scanner(new FileInputStream ("test.txt"));
/*
 in my text {1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 }
 */
while (in.hasNextInt())
{
    System.out.print(in.nextInt());

}
in=new Scanner(new FileInputStream ("test.txt")); 
while (in.hasNextInt())
{
    System.out.print(in.nextInt());
}
```

However, it would make more sense to store the values you already read from the file and re-use them, instead of reading from the file again (unless there's a posibility that the content of the file has changed).

Comment: that mean there is no function to repeat the value again 
thank you so much :)